# What does <overflow> mean during CUDA profiling?

Tags: cuda, profiling, gpu

I have noticed this wierd behaviour during CUDA code profiling using nvprof or nvvp. Instead of the actual values of the counters, it displays an overflow.

For example, I profile my application using

```
 nvprof --print-gpu-trace --metrics  warp_execution_efficiency ./CUDA-EC
```

And the result I am getting is this:

```
Device           Kernel                      Warp Execution Efficiency
Tesla K20m (0)   fix_errors1_warp_cop        <OVERFLOW>
```

Can somebody tell me how to avoid this and fetch actual value? This behaviour also occurs when I use nvvp.

Comment: Which CUDA version are you using?  Can you provide a short, complete code, which will produce this output (and the steps to produce it)?

Comment: As far as I am aware this can happen with long-running kernels that cause event counters in the GPU hardware to overflow (on older GPUs these comprise only 32 bit, best I recall). Try reducing the runtime of the kernel(s) affected.

Comment: This is CUDA 6.5. I am sorry but the code is too big and has multiple files. @njuffa, this kernel runs for about 3 seconds on K20m.

Comment: A 32-bit counter incrementing every cycle at the K20m base clock frequency of 706 MHz would overflow after 6.08 seconds, so I am not sure whether my working hypothesis is applicable at all. If there is an easy way to reduce the run-time of this kernel for a quick experiment it might be worth a try as a sanity check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A counter reports OVERFLOW if the physical hardware counter reached its maximum value during the capture and the profiler cannot determine a correct value. The majority of hardware counters on NVIDIA GPUs are 32 bits. In Maxwell the SM counter width was increased to ~40 bits.

A number of the PM experiments can increment a physical counter by 6 bits (0-63) per cycle. At 1 GHz a 32-bit counter has a minimum overflow time of ~68ms. In practice many of the more complex experiments will overflow when kernels exceed 1 second.

In order to avoid overflow the developer may have to reduce the execution time of the kernel by reducing the data set or breaking the kernel into multiple launches.

The NVIDIA tools teams are working on multiple software and hardware solutions to eliminate overflow issues in longer running kernels. Unfortunately, these solution take time to implement.

Comment: Thanks guys, I brought the kernel timings to 1.5 seconds by reducing the data size, and this counter worked now. I am happy. I have been getting insufficient data from nvvp/nvprof for long and I used to blame the drivers for that :\